# excluding Windows 7.pvm from Time Machine

Tags: time-machine, ms-office, parallels-desktop

If I exclude the file: MacHD>User>FH>Documents>Parallels>Windows 7.pvm from the backup made by Time Machine, do MS Word and Excel files get backed up?

I have configured Parallels 8 to Share Mac User folder w/Windows and to Map Mac Volumes to Windows. All my MS Office files are stored in Mac HD->Users->FH->Documents.

I'm a bit confused. Any thought would be terrific.

Thx,

FH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they should get backed up, since your MS Word and Excel files are located in your Mac User Documents folder *and not* the Parallels .pvm. If they were located within your Parallels .pvm and it's excluded, then they would not be backed up.

The .pvm file essentially acts as the hard disk drive for Parallels, and is basically a separate container that exists somewhat isolated from your Mac's environment. It can share files and folders with your Mac, although anything outside of it's .pvm belongs to OS X.